# there was an error running the selected code generator in .net6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I use .net 6 and when I use Add an ASP.NET Core MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework Core(I do this in Area). I get an error.

I searched a lot but did not find any

error:

[image]

DBContext:

```
namespace PotLearn.DataLayer.Context
{
    public class PotLearnContext:DbContext
    {
        public PotLearnContext(DbContextOptions<PotLearnContext> options)
    : base(options)
        {
        }
        #region User
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
#region DataBase Context
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PotLearnConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<PotLearnContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
#endregion
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}




app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "areas",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.Run();
```

How can I fix this error?

Thankyou.

Comment: If you try to clean and rebuild,will it be solved?

Comment: No unfortunately it was not resolved

Answer (score 7):

This is issue seems to be version issue. Your .NET 6.0 is not matching with the version with Web.CodeGeneration.

**SOLUTION - 1:**
Go to NuGet package Manager (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution). Then go to Updates and update the packages showing in it.

**SOLUTION - 2:**
Clean and Rebuild your whole Solution, NOT just the project.

**SOLUTION - 3:-**
If **SOLUTION - 1** is not working then go to Browse tab and then search for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration and based on your .NET project, install the version by selecting the version number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work:(

Comment: Check your versions of "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design". If you have lower versions, update it to the latest one. If you don't have it, then install it.

Comment: I did this but it did not work

Comment: @sina, can you check your 'PotLearnContext' class. Does it have base constructor overridden?

Comment: yes it has a overridden constructor

Comment: @sina I noticed that you wrote your DbContext in Program.cs instead of Startup.cs. Please try to write your Dbcontext dependency in Startup.cs file under ConfigureServices(). The line starting from UseHttpsRedirection() until the end should be in Configure().

Comment: But There isn't Startup.cs in .net 6

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, love to hear what would be the solution.

Comment: @sina and @Ben in your Program.cs can you please try this: `builder.Services.AddDbContext<PotLearnContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString).ConnectionString;)` 

Notice, I have added `ConnectionString` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to fix this issue for a long time in .Net 6, when I was trying to install "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" which happen to read in the console:

> NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common.
> project project.xxx to resolve this issue.
> project.xxx -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.2.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.2.0)
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils 6.0.7 -> Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared 6.0.7

My problem was solved after replacing
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils** with **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common**

And
**Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces** with **Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared**

Comment: I can't fix using this code